# Draw with multiple fingers/styluses simultaneously on a touchscreen

Tags: gnome, wayland, touch-screen, touch, multi-touch

I have a large touchscreen display that I would like to use for drawing with either my fingers or/and styluses.

I can do this perfectly fine under Android, multiple people can use the display at the same time, drawing at different areas.

However, when running Wayland (Gnome), touch events are interpreted as mouse-clicks or multi-touch events such as zoom or rotate. Is it possible to draw multiple lines, for example in Gimp on Wayland like that?

Comment: Don't you see the raw touch events with `evtest`?