# Multi-hand drawing on ir-board

Tags: debian, xorg, tablet, multi-touch, xournal

I have many LUMIOBOARD DVIRT-9101. It recognizes as:

```
[    2.309343] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.498330] usb 1-2.2.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    2.720902] usb 1-2.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=255e, idProduct=8085, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    2.720910] usb 1-2.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.720913] usb 1-2.2.1: Manufacturer: IrScreen cc
[    2.735815] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.735819] usbhid: USB HID core driver
<...>
[    2.956773] input: IrScreen cc Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2.1/1-2.2.1:1.0/0003:255E:8085.0002/input/input4
[    2.956952] hid-generic 0003:255E:8085.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [IrScreen cc] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2.1/input0
[    2.957187] input: IrScreen cc Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2.1/1-2.2.1:1.1/0003:255E:8085.0003/input/input6
[    2.957338] input: IrScreen cc Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2.1/1-2.2.1:1.1/0003:255E:8085.0003/input/input7
[    3.014684] hid-generic 0003:255E:8085.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [IrScreen cc] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2.1/input1
```

Original program (SensStudio) only exists for Windows. I launched it with Wine, but wine doesn't support multi-touch, as I read.

Then I tried many others (Openboard, Xournal++, rainbow-board_0.8.1 and many others) with Debian 11 and Ubuntu 20.04.4.

Only 1 line drawing.

Manufacturer's program (SensStudio) and "rainbow-board" support multi-hand writing under Windows. No super-driver is used. It detects as touchscreen, as under linux.

I use Xorg, but see same problem with Wayland: [Draw with multiple fingers/styluses simultaneously on a touchscreen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710275/draw-with-multiple-fingers-styluses-simultaneously-on-a-touchscreen/742132#742132)

What can I do to resolve this problem? Can I add multi-touch support in Wine (from licensed Windows of course)?

Some people tell to try this, but I'm not sure It helps:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multi-pointer_X

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't understand, because you AI.
But I write more simple: Many people want to write on 1 ir-board. I need program for Linux to do that.